# HTML5 drag and drop file upload with multiple target drop areas on a page

Tags: jquery, html, upload, drag-and-drop

Are there any Javascript solutions to allow HTML5 drag and drop upload to multiple targets on a web page?

**Example**

> Five different folders on a web page and the user can simply drag
>   files and drop in target folder to upload it to that folder.

So far, I got drag and drop uploading done to single target. But I would like something that works with multiple targets on the page. As well has queueing options so not all files are uploaded at once which might jam server.

Solutions I am looking at are:

- http://code.google.com/p/html5uploader/
- http://www.uploadify.com/
- http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

Answer (score 4):

Drag and drop features only work with modern browsers. if you intend to support IE, I don't recommend the feature.

Your need is quite specific, you won't find such thing ready-made online. There is a very good tutorial do drag and drop you can find it here

http://robertnyman.com/2010/12/16/utilizing-the-html5-file-api-to-choose-upload-preview-and-see-progress-for-multiple-files/